# Get the JScrollPane of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a JTable object. How can I get a reference to the JScrollPane the JTable is in?

I tried getParent() but that returns `null`.

EDIT:

My Bad.

As mentioned in one of the comments I'm trying to create my custom JTable that has a row header by default without manually having to add it. The problem is to add the row header one needs to call `scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(rowHeader);`. The problem is that I was calling `getParent()` in the constructor befpre the table actually has a parent and before `jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);` was called.

So this can't be solved in one step but only afterwards.

Comment: I think a JTable does not contain a JScrollPane (unless you specifically place it in a JScrollPane, but then you can acces it in another way), could you tell me what you would like to do with this JScrollPane?

Comment: @Duckdoom5 I want to create my custom JTable with a row header. To set the row header one needs to call `scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(rowHeader);`

Comment: After your edit... what is your question?

Comment: None really because I do not see a way this can be done the way I wanted it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane)SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, myTable);
```

You can find more information about this method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorOfClass%28java.lang.Class,%20java.awt.Component%29).

Comment: I forgot to cast it to JScrollPane, since that method returns a Container. It works now.

Comment: The problem is that the scroll pane is not the tables parent or ancestor. `jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);` does not affect component hierarchy.

Comment: @Baldus, I know I had to cast it, still didn't work cus the JTable is not created in a JScrollPane

Comment: I don't know how you are trying it, but it works for me.

Comment: `jTable1 = new JTable();`      `jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);`

Comment: Then this works, I have tried several times: `JScrollPane scrollPane2 = (JScrollPane)SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, jTable1);`

Comment: you are right. my fault. see edit in question I will shortly post.